# Is there a way to create a network of word associations using a bi-partite network analysis in R?

Tags: r, networking, text-mining

I have a text file with words from historical accounts and I want to visualise the species and frequency of words associated with them.

So far I have tried using the following code with a txt file of all the historical documents in one doc but want to ask if there is specific formatting of a csv to then input into R for a bipartite network graph:

```
"""library(ggraph)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(pdftools)
library(tm)
library(readtext)
library(tidytext)
library(igraph)
library(tidyr)
library(FactoMineR)
library(factoextra)
library(flextable)
library(GGally)
library(ggdendro)
library(network)
library(Matrix)
library(quanteda)
library(stringr)
library(quanteda.textstats)

options(stringsAsFactors = F)
options(scipen = 999)
options(max.print=1000)

# Read in text--------
wordbase <- readtext("mq_bird_stories.txt")

# List of extra words to remove---------
extrawords <- c("the", "can", "get", "Ccchants", "make", "making", "house", "torn", "tree", "man", "however", "upon", "instructs", "wife", "coming","without", "mother", "versions","variant", "version", "thus", "got","throws", "are", "has", "already", "asks", "sacra", "can", "brings", "one", "look", "sees", "tonaheiee", "wants", "later",
                "dont", "even", "may", "but", "will", "turn", "sing", "swallows", "alba",  "gives", "find", "other","tonaheieee", "away","day","comes","another",
                "much", "first", "but", "see", "new", "back","goes", "go","songs",  "returns", "take","takes","come",
                "many", "less", "now", "well", "taught", "like", "puts", "slits", "sends", "tell","tells","open","mentions",
                "often", "every", "said", "two", "and", "handsome", "husband", "bring", "lives","gets", "von", "den", "steinen", "handy")

# Clean the data-------
darwin <- wordbase %>%
  paste0(collapse = " ") %>%
  stringr::str_squish() %>%
  stringr::str_remove_all("\\(") %>% 
  stringr::str_remove_all("\\)") %>% 
  stringr::str_remove_all("!") %>% 
  stringr::str_remove_all(",") %>% 
  stringr::str_remove_all(";") %>% 
  stringr::str_remove_all("\\?") %>% 
  stringr::str_split(fixed(".")) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  tm :: removeWords(extrawords) %>% 
  paste0(collapse = " ")




# One method for calculating frequencies of bigrams------
# Process into a table of words
darwin_split <- darwin %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  tidytext::unnest_tokens(words, value)

# Create data frame of bigrams-------
darwin_words <- darwin_split %>%
  dplyr::rename(word1 = words) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(word2 = c(word1[2:length(word1)], NA)) %>%
  na.omit()

# Calculate frequency of bigrams-----
darwin2grams <- darwin_words %>%
  dplyr::mutate(bigram = paste(word1, word2, sep = " ")) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(bigram) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(frequency = n()) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(-frequency)

# Define stopwords
stps <- paste0(tm::stopwords(kind = "en"), collapse = "\\b|\\b")

# Remove stopwords from bigram table
darwin2grams_clean <- darwin2grams %>%
  dplyr::filter(!str_detect(bigram, stps))




# Another method for calculating frequencies of bigrams
# Clean corpus
darwin_clean <- darwin %>%
  stringr::str_to_title()

# Tokenize corpus----
darwin_tokzd <- quanteda::tokens(darwin_clean)

# Extract bigrams------
BiGrams <- darwin_tokzd %>% 
  quanteda::tokens_remove(stopwords("en")) %>% 
  quanteda::tokens_select(pattern = "^[A-Z]", 
                          valuetype = "regex",
                          case_insensitive = FALSE, 
                          padding = TRUE) %>% 
  quanteda.textstats::textstat_collocations(min_count = 1, tolower = FALSE)

# read in and process text
darwinsentences <- darwin %>%
  stringr::str_squish() %>%
  tokenizers::tokenize_sentences(.) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  stringr::str_remove_all("- ") %>%
  stringr::str_replace_all("\\W", " ") %>%
  stringr::str_squish()
# inspect data
head(darwinsentences)

darwincorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(darwinsentences))

# clean corpus-----
darwincorpusclean <- darwincorpus %>%
  tm::tm_map(removeNumbers) %>%
  tm::tm_map(tolower) %>%
  tm::tm_map(removeWords, stopwords()) %>%
  tm::tm_map(removeWords, extrawords)
# create document term matrix
darwindtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(darwincorpusclean, control=list(bounds = list(global=c(1, Inf)), weighting = weightBin))
# convert dtm into sparse matrix
darwinsdtm <- Matrix::sparseMatrix(i = darwindtm$i, j = darwindtm$j, 
                                   x = darwindtm$v, 
                                   dims = c(darwindtm$nrow, darwindtm$ncol),
                                   dimnames = dimnames(darwindtm))
# calculate co-occurrence counts
coocurrences <- t(darwinsdtm) %*% darwinsdtm
# convert into matrix
collocates <- as.matrix(coocurrences)
# inspect size of matrix
ncol(collocates)
#provide some summary stats
summary(rowSums(collocates))

#visualising collocations

# load function for co-occurrence calculation
source("https://slcladal.github.io/rscripts/calculateCoocStatistics.R")
# define term
coocTerm <- "pigeon"
# calculate co-occurrence statistics
coocs <- calculateCoocStatistics(coocTerm, darwinsdtm, measure="LOGLIK")
# inspect results
coocs[1:50]

coocdf <- coocs %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(CollStrength = coocs,
                Term = names(coocs)) %>%
  dplyr::filter(CollStrength > 0)

###Make graph - visualize association strengths------

ggplot(coocdf, aes(x = reorder(Term, CollStrength, mean), y = CollStrength)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(y = "")


##network
net = network::network(collocates_redux, 
                       directed = FALSE,
                       ignore.eval = FALSE,
                       names.eval = "weights")
# vertex names
network.vertex.names(net) = rownames(collocates_redux)
# inspect object
net

ggnet2(net,label = TRUE, 
       label.size = 4,
       alpha = 0.2,
       size.cut = 3,
       edge.alpha = 0.3) +
  guides(color = FALSE, size = FALSE)"""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest taking a look at the netCoin package. If you can transform your data into nodes and links data frames, then you can easily get a high quality network visualization:

```
#Example of links data frame
links <-
  data.frame(
    matrix(
      c(
        "Person A","Account 1", "not link",
        "Person A","Account 2", "link",
        "Person B","Account 2", "link",
        "Person B","Account 3", "not link",
        "Person B","Account 4", "link",
        "Person C","Account 4", "link"
      ),
      nrow = 6,
      ncol = 3,
      byrow = TRUE,
      dimnames = list(NULL,
                      c("Source", "Target", "other_links_column"))
    ),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

#Example of nodes data frame
nodes <-
  data.frame(
    matrix(
      c(
        "Person A","person",
        "Person B","person",
        "Person C","person",
        "Account 1", "account",
        "Account 2", "account",
        "Account 3", "account",
        "Account 4", "account"
      ),
      nrow = 7,
      ncol = 2,
      byrow = TRUE,
      dimnames = list(NULL,
                      c("name", "other_nodes_column"))
    ),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

install.packages("netCoin") #may need to install the netCoin package
library(netCoin)
?netCoin #displays netCoin Help to see all the function options


graph_df <- netCoin(nodes =  nodes, #Data frame of unique nodes and their attributes #Must contain name column
                     links = links, #Data frame of links and their attributes #Must contain Source and Target columns
                     cex = 1.25, #Font size
                     color = "other_nodes_column", #Column in node data frame to determine node color 
                     shape = "other_nodes_column", #Column in node data frame to determine node shape                    
                     main = "This is the title of my visualization", #Visualization title
                     controls = 1:5, #Controls that will be shown in the visualization (maximum of 5)
                     dir = "folder-with-viz-output") #Output folder for the visualization #Entire folder should be exported as a zip file

plot(graph_df) #Command to display the visualization
```